# Is there a way to checkout a Github repo and branch without setting up a remote?

Tags: git, github, pull-request, git-checkout

To evaluate a pull request to our project repo seems to require doing this:

```
git remote add newcontributor https://github.com/newcontributor/ourproject
git fetch newcontributor
git checkout newcontributor/pr-branch
...
git remote rm newcontributor
```

Is there a simpler way?

Comment: `git fetch origin pr/{id}/head`?

Comment: How would that work? Is `pr` meant to automatically track pull requests? I don't have anything like that.

Comment: I did not test it but [the documentation of git fetch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) says, that you can specify a URL as repository. I thing this mean that `git pull https://github.com/newcontributor/ourproject pr-branch` should work. Maybe you can test it.^^

Comment: @SteveBennett - Github automatically creates these meta branches in your repository.

Comment: @JosephSilber really? I don't see them with `git branch -a`. Hmm.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, Github makes this easy. At the bottom of the Pull Request page, there's a link:

[image]

This gives the commands, using `git pull` to merge from a URL:

```
git checkout -b newcontributor-prbranch master
git pull https://github.com/newcontributor/ourproject.git pr-branch
```